# Do any plants exhibit hormonal changes similar to puberty?

Tags: botany

Just what the title states.

Are there any plants/trees that exhibit a growth spurt at a definite interval after the shoot appears?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In flowering plants (the angiosperms) there are several developmental transitions in the life of the plant. I won't list the plants, because the list includes pretty much all of them (although the magnitude in the change of developmental pace differs widely between taxa and environments).

First there is **seed germination**, which is controlled hormonally. Absence of germination is usually imposed by abscisic acid, whilst germination is caused at the appropriate time by gibberellic acid and ethylene (among other things; [Holdsworth, Bentsink & Soppe, 2008](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1469-8137.2008.02437.x)).

Next, in many herbaceous species there is a **transition between a spreading growth stage (e.g. rosette growth) and the flowering stage**. The 'growth spurt' here is the differentiation and elongation of the flowering stem, and then subsequently the sudden flowering of buds. The transition is also controlled hormonally, by a variety of hormones including auxin ([Zhao, 2010](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-arplant-042809-112308)), gibberellic acid, ethylene ([Schaller, 2012](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/1741-7007-10-9)), and the long anticipated, recently confirmed florigen ([Choi, 2012](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pbio.1001311)). Ethylene and abscisic acid then play important roles in the next developmental transition when seeds and fruits are produced and dehisced.

Small RNAs are also now being revealed to play a large role in controlling the timing of developmental, but they are upstream of the hormonal changes. In particular some key miRNAs are involved in auxin-based regulation of branching, and in embryogenesis ([Nodine & Bartel, 2010](http://dx.doi.org/10.1101/gad.1986710)), and RNA silencing is involved in the switch from rosette growth to flowering growth (reviewed in [Poethig, 2009](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.gde.2009.06.001) and [Baurle & Dean 2006](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cell.2006.05.005)).

---

- [**Bäurle I, Dean C**. 2006. The Timing of Developmental Transitions in Plants. Cell 125: 655–664.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cell.2006.05.005)
- [**Choi CQ**. 2012. A Blossoming Field of Research: How Florigen Is Transported to Create Flowers. PLoS Biol 10: e1001311.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pbio.1001311)
- [**Holdsworth MJ, Bentsink L, Soppe WJJ**. 2008. Molecular networks regulating Arabidopsis seed maturation, after-ripening, dormancy and germination. New Phytologist 179: 33–54.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1469-8137.2008.02437.x)
- [**Nodine MD, Bartel DP**. 2010. MicroRNAs Prevent Precocious Gene Expression and Enable Pattern Formation During Plant Embryogenesis. Genes Dev 24: 2678–2692.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1101/gad.1986710)
- [**Poethig RS**. 2009. Small RNAs and developmental timing in plants. Curr Opin Genet Dev 19: 374–378.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.gde.2009.06.001)
- [**Schaller GE**. 2012. Ethylene and the regulation of plant development. BMC Biology 10: 9.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/1741-7007-10-9)
- [**Zhao Y**. 2010. Auxin Biosynthesis and Its Role in Plant Development.](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-arplant-042809-112308)